# How to center two inline-block p in a div container?

Tags: html, css, centering

In a `div`, I have two `p` with different style, and I want to center the two `p` as one in `div`.

If only one `p`, I just set `width: 100%` and `text-align: center` to `p`.

But how to center two `p` just like single `p` in `div`?

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
.first {
    color: red;
}
.second {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p class="first">one</p>
    <p class="second">two</p>
</div>
```

The result just like this:

[image]

Comment: `text-align: center;` on div will do the job

Comment: Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **text-align: center;** to div Tag

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
.first {
    color: red;
}
.second {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p class="first">one</p>
    <p class="second">two</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow,  I think this is simplest way to solve this. Thanks all of you for your help.

Comment: If I don't need the gap between two `p`, the flexbox seems better.

Comment: I just found I can write two `p` tag in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Using a flexbox and auto `margin` for the `div`

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
.first {
    color: red;
}
.second {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p class="first">one</p>
    <p class="second">two</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
.first {
    color: red;
}
.second {
    color: blue;
}

div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p class="first">one</p>
    <p class="second">two</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) approach...

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.first {
  color: red;
}

.second {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="first">one</p>
  <p class="second">two</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for.

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
    }
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
.first {
    color: red;
}
.second {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p class="first">one</p>
    <p class="second">two</p>
</div>
```